# SignalProducer does not started in my case using ReactiveSwift

Tags: reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

Suppose I'd like to read a value from UseDefaults, if it fails, try to ask server for it , I wrote this code, but it will not execute:

```
func getAuthorizationCode() -> SignalProducer<String, MoyaError> {
    if let authCode = UserDefaults.string(forKey: .authorizationCode) {
        return SignalProducer(value: authCode)
    }

    let provider = ReactiveSwiftMoyaProvider<UserService>()
    return  provider.request(.authorization).flatMap(.concat) {
        response -> SignalProducer<String, Moya.MoyaError> in

        let json = JSON(data: response.data)
        log.debug("Authorization response:\(json) ")
        let authCode = json["authorizationcode"].stringValue
        return SignalProducer(value: authCode)
    }

}
```

getAuthorizationCode().start {
        event in 
       case let .value(value):
            print(value)
       case let .failed(error):
           print(error)
   }
What's more, If I'd like to execute another network request, what should I do?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you test `ReactiveSwiftMoyaProvider<UserService>` on it's own to ensure that's working?

Comment: Oh...thank you! I found the reason, `provider` has been destroyed after the function called. so any suggestion how to make the lifetime of `SignalProducer` longer?

Comment: Can you post some details about how `ReactiveSwiftMoyaProvider` is implemented? In terms of memory management, I think the producer returned from `getAuthorizationCode()` should retain the producer from `provider.request(.authorization)` via the `flatMap`. So I think `provider` must be somehow disposing the producer upon deinitialization.

Comment: Well, check here: https://github.com/Moya/Moya/blob/master/Sources/ReactiveMoya/ReactiveSwiftMoyaProvider.swift

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the producer returned from `provider.request(.authorization)` references the provider weakly so it can use it to kick off the request. I think you just have to keep the provider around in a property. If you want to get clever to avoid using a stored property, maybe you can capture it in that `flatMap` closure  to keep it alive as long as your SignalProducer is alive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, `provider` needs to be kept alive for your SignalProducer to work. To avoid having to store `provider` in an instance var somewhere, you could maybe do what Matt Gallagher suggests in [this Cocoa with Love post](https://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/resources-releases-reentrancy.html#unconventional-uses-of-withextendedlifetime), which is to put `withExtendedLifetime(provider) {}` somewhere in your `flatMap` closure in order to keep `provider` alive as long your producer is alive. This is basically just a way to retain `provider` without the compiler complaining about an unused variable.

Comment: There is a better solution here: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/issues/358

Comment: That is nicer! I had no idea you could just use `_ = ...` to avoid the unused expression warning.